# Error taking image resource

Tags: android

I'm trying to add drawer icon to action bar but it showing error in R.drawable.ic_drawer.
I tried this:

```
 drawerListener =new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, //host activity (use getActivity() if in other code file to access host activity
            drawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //icon for drawer
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close ){

        //on opening of drawer
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            //wrie the event you want to create after the drawer is fully opened
            //make a toast for instance
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        //on closing of drawer
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            //wrie the event you want to create after the drawer is fully closed
            //make a toast for instance
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }


    };
```

Comment: i know that it sound silly, but have you save the image in the res folder? can you see it in the R file?

Comment: yes i've placed the icon in drawable folder.But i don't see it in R file. How to put it there manually?

Comment: Ok, the best way is to clean & build you project

Comment: ic_launcher is also not in  R file

Comment: Have you imported R.android?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you imported `android.R`.
If so, delete this import and import your own `R`.

To import your `R` do this:

```
import yourPackage.R
```

replace `youPackage` with your package.

Comment: Ty for editing me, i wrote it from the phone so i couldnt add it as code